# Shared preferences not saving the dta after onclick button

Tags: android

i an trying to save the data but button click my data isn't save .pl tell me any solution and error in my code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main1);
prefs=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (prefs.contains(Uname))
      {
        username.setText(prefs.getString(Uname, ""));

      }
      if (prefs.contains(Pass))
      {
          password.setText(prefs.getString(Pass, ""));

      }
      if (prefs.contains(Code))
      {
          opcode.setText(prefs.getString(Code, ""));

      }

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    }`
});
```

}

Comment: Where is your SAVE PREFERENCE code on button click event?

Comment: I see only getting a value... where do you **put** it?

Comment: Your click listener is empty

Comment: wrong button click event ends btnlogin with one brace excess!

Answer (score 1):

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editor e = prefs.edit();
        e.putString(Uname, username.getText().toString());
        e.putString(Pass, password.getText().toString());
        e.putString(Code, opcode.getText().toString());
        e.commit();
    }

});
```